# i can't install androidx.preference library

Tags: android, gradle, installation, project-structure

i want to install preference library from androidx. when i go to project structure to add this library :
1. i don't have 1.1.0 version. i only have 1.1.0-alpha05 and 1.0.0 versions.
2. when i want to install any version of this library i get :
    ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.preference:preference:VERSION

** i don't have same problem with other libraries

this is my gradle (app) module:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notebook_v2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

}
```

and this is gradle(project) module:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try to put low versions of the library and android studio suggest you to the most latest stable available version. And also you can check the versions of [androidX releases here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions)

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
```

And maybe you need update build tools